# Organize simple form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create a simple page. Page has table with some product information(id,Name,Order, Size etc), page listener, filter form(products from date1 to date2, products size...). what is best way to organize such pages? Also i want to use ajax, but it's not necessary.

My vision:

1. `PageListener<T>` class with method `List<t> GetPage(int pageNumber)`
2. ProductsViewModel class with `List<product>` field, current page, page info, so on
3. Filter class. This class i will be able to use for filter and validation data.

   class Filter
   {
       Datetime date1;
       Datetime date2;
       int maxSize;
       int minSize;
       ....
       public List FilterData(List data);
   }
4. One action method with two parametrs

   ActionResult Show(Filter filter,int pageNumber){}

Is it good solution?

Comment: You might wanna use `PagedList` for paging data. http://pagedlist.codeplex.com/